# Selenium Unknown sessionId

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have:
Chrome version: 65.0.3325.146
Chrom driver version: 2.36.540470
Selenium webdriver: 3.9.1

In the middle of the test it's looks like the chrome is stuck, do nothing, and I can see in chrome driver console error message: "Unable to retrieve document state unknown error: unknown sessionId"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got any examples of your code?

Comment: Your _code trials_ and relevant _HTML_ please.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, upgrade the chrome webdriver version solved this problem.